# The "nameof " operator,"expression cannot be used in an argument to nameof"

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I got a simple class:

```
public class Stu
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If I do like this:

```
var stu = new Stu();
Console.WriteLine(nameof(stu.Name));
```

it works well.
but this:

```
Console.WriteLine(nameof(new Stu().Name));
```

or this:

```
Console.WriteLine(nameof((new Stu()).Name));
```

do not work.  The compiler tells me: "expression cannot be used in an argument to nameof".

I don't know why.  What does the tip mean?  What is the correct parameter type of the operator "nameof()"?

I have searched the web.  [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/the-new-feature-of-C-Sharp-6-0-nameof-operator/) page tells me the "expression may be a property-group or a method-group", but is the expression "new Stu().Name" not a "property-group"?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You probably want

```
nameof(Stu.Name)
```

`nameof()` gets some special syntax so you don't have to instantiate a class to get the name of one of its properties, and other similar scenarios.

Comment: `Name` doesn't need to be static to refer to it within the `nameof` operator. It gets special syntax to be able to resolve static OR instance members

Comment: The expected result of the `nameof` operator is transformed into a constant string during compilation.